# How to increase the speed of bulk inserts with GORM?

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am using v2 GORM's [CreateInBatches](https://gorm.io/docs/create.html#Batch-Insert) and changed `SkipDefaultTransaction: true` [as mentioned in the "Performance" page](https://gorm.io/docs/performance.html#Disable-Default-Transaction), but I find that +350k records inserted in batches of 1000 take almost 3 minutes.

I tried removing the gorm.Model{} fields but didn't see much improvement.

What can I do to increase bulk-insert speed?

EDIT for anyone reading this with the same problem: I ended up saving my data in CSVs and importing it with [pg_bulkload](https://github.com/ossc-db/pg_bulkload) - got 1 million rows imported in 1 second *(on a server with lots of cores & RAM)*

Comment: If further increasing the batch size doesn't increase the speed, it's unlikely you can do much more from gorm. Do you have evidence that it can actually go faster (like, what speed can you get using a command-line client, or doing a COPY FROM at the server?).

Comment: Also, what database are you using, are there indices on the target table?

Comment: ^ I'm using PostgreSQL and removed the indexes to no avail... I ended up saving my data in CSVs and importing them with pg_bulkload (which basically does a COPY like you said, so thanks for your replies).

Info for other people with the same problem reading this: got 1 million rows imported in 1 second (with lots of cores & RAM).